# Changing div id Each time the loop is run

Tags: php, javascript, loops, html

I've got this echo in a loop where it's making a bunch of rows but all with the same id'ed div.

For each row/loop run is there a way to change the id of the div being created?

Like..

div id=content1
div id=content2
etc...

Then I can also have it

loadContent('#content1'...
loadContent('#content2'...
etc...

```
echo "<tr class=\"expand-child\"><td colspan=\"11\" height=\"100px\">$name1<br>"; ?> <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'Earnings-Disclaimer.html');">Link 1</a> <?php echo "<div id=\"content\"></div></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr class=\"expand-child\"><td colspan=\"11\" height=\"100px\">$name1<br>";
    ?> <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content<?php echo $i;?>', 'Earnings-Disclaimer.html');">Link 1</a> <?php echo "<div id=\"content".$i."\"></div></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your loop is, but something like this would work

```
<?php
$i++;
foreach($loop as $key=>$name1)
{
    echo "<tr class=\"expand-child\"><td colspan=\"11\" height=\"100px\">$name1<br>"; ?> <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content<?php echo $i; ?>', 'Earnings-Disclaimer.html');">Link 1</a> <?php echo "<div id=\"content\"></div></td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

or more readable

```
<?php
$i++;
foreach($loop as $key=>$name1)
{
    ?>
    <tr class="expand-child">
        <td colspan="11" height="100px">
            <?=$name1?><br>
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content<?=$i?>', 'Earnings-Disclaimer.html');">Link 1</a> 
            <div id="content<?=$i?>"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```